# Javascript quotes indexer

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, dynamic-html

I have created a Javascript to so that if I add quotes to below script it should place in `<p></p>`element.

```
const quotes = [
  { quotes: 'Be yourself; everyone else is already taken' },
  { quotes: 'So Many Books, So Little Time' },
  { quotes: "Strangers think I'm Quiet. My Friends think I'm outgoing. My best friends know that I'm Completely Insane" },
  { quotes: 'A room without books is like a body without soul' },
  { quotes: 'You only live once, but if you do it right, once is enough' },
];
function quoteindexer() {
  quotesView.innerHTML = quotes[i].quotes;
}
```

My html Code

```
<p class="quotes" id="quoteindexer"></p>
```

But I needed all the quotes to be displayed in different `<p></p>` elements itself. That is the number of quotes should be equal to number of `<p></p>` created. I am new to Javascript so please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to go through each quote and create a paragraph for it:

```
const quotes = [
    { quotes: 'Be yourself; everyone else is already taken' },
    { quotes: 'So Many Books, So Little Time' },
    { quotes: "Strangers think I'm Quiet. My Friends think I'm outgoing. My best friends know that I'm Completely Insane" },
    { quotes: 'A room without books is like a body without soul' },
    { quotes: 'You only live once, but if you do it right, once is enough' },
];

var quotesHtml = quotes.map(function(q) {
    return '<p class="quotes">'+ q.quotes +'</p>'
}).join('\n');

function quoteindexer() {
    quotesView.innerHTML = quotesHtml;
}
```

Comment: do we need to passin the '\n' in .join() ? cant we just use .join('') ?

Comment: Not needed of course, just preference to have each <p> in a new line if you're going to read the html

Answer (score 1):

```js
var quotes = [
      { quotes: 'Be yourself; everyone else is already taken' },
      { quotes: 'So Many Books, So Little Time' },
      { quotes: "Strangers think I'm Quiet. My Friends think I'm outgoing. My best friends know that I'm Completely Insane" },
      { quotes: 'A room without books is like a body without soul' },
      { quotes: 'You only live once, but if you do it right, once is enough' }
    ];
    function quoteindexer(arrayQ) {
      let quotesView = document.getElementById('quotesView'); //target your container
      for(var j in arrayQ){
     
         //pass quotes into the container
        quotesView.innerHTML +='<p class="quotes">'; 
        quotesView.innerHTML += quotes[j].quotes;
        quotesView.innerHTML += '</p>';
      }
      
    }
    //
    quoteindexer(quotes);
```

```html
<div id='quotesView'></div>
<style>
.quotes{
 background: #dde;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 5px;
 margin: 3px;
}

</style>
```

check this out

```html
<div id="quotesView"></div>
```

Comment: It only shows one quote. I needed to show all quotes in separate <div> without actually writing html code

Comment: Should I have to place the <p class="quotes">  inside the given div

Comment: <div id="quotesView" >     all your quoutes will enter here    </div>

Comment: I think there is something mistake in code. It doesn't display anything!

Comment: yea i have fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Simpy use **Array.map() methode**. Example :

```js
const quotes = [
  { quotes: 'Be yourself; everyone else is already taken' },
  { quotes: 'So Many Books, So Little Time' },
  { quotes: "Strangers think I'm Quiet. My Friends think I'm outgoing. My best friends know that I'm Completely Insane" },
  { quotes: 'A room without books is like a body without soul' },
  { quotes: 'You only live once, but if you do it right, once is enough' }
]

let container = document.getElementById("myQuotes")

let Allquotes = quotes.map(myquote =>{
 return `<p>${myquote.quotes}</p> \n`
  
})
container.innerHTML = Allquotes
```

```html
<div id="myQuotes">

</div>
```

Comment: Although it worked but it shows a quoma (" , " ) after each quotes. Please solve it.

Comment: Any body help me.